# PHP: Form to txt file

Tags: php, html, xampp

I have been developing a testing website that uses a PHP script to dump data into a txt file for a no database option.

My `XAMPP` setup says my post variable is undefined, although I'm sure it's not.

I tried pre-creating the text file with the correct name (blank), and I have not messed with permissions on my Mac.

How can I write this script?

Comment: Please share the code you tried

Comment: please post your code - both backend and the HTML sending the form...

Comment: Hey Ley. Have you tried a simple `var_dump($_POST,$_GET);` to see if the form is being submitted properly? It may be empty because it is being sent as a GET request...

Answer (score 0):

Run this in your php file and you should see myfile.txt in the folder where your php file is.

```
$filepath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/myfile.txt'; //Current folder and this filename
$text = 'New Line of text'; //You input text

if(file_exists($filepath)) //If file created, append text
{
   file_put_contents($filepath, $text, FILE_APPEND);
}else{
   file_put_contents($filepath, $text);
}
```

Use `var_dump($_POST);` to check your post. Make sure the form is set to `method='POST'`.

Answer (score 0):

Making sure you've set the permissions for the PHP saving to the text file and the file itself to writeable, something like this should fix your problem.

```
<form method="post" action="?submitted=true">
    <input type="text" name="itemA"/>
    <input type="text" name="itemB"/>
    <input type="text" name="itemC"/>
    <button type="submit"><button>
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['submitted']) && isset($_POST)) {
        $file = "textfile.txt"; 
        $text = "";
        foreach($_POST as $item) {
            $text .= $item;
        }

        if($text > "") {
            file_put_contents($file, $text);
        } else {
            echo "No items in POST!";
        }
    }
?>
```